# How to insert LONG BINARY from SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, plsql

I need to get a copy of a SQL Server 2008 table into an Oracle RDBMS. I have database link for SQL Server, database has a table which contains LONG BINARY type column.

When I issue

```
create table test_ora as select * from mssqltable@dblink
```

I get the error

> Can't convert LONG

I tried to use `to_lob`, `to_char`, `hextoraw` and a ream of Oracle conversion function but still hasn't defeated the issue. Do you have any ideas?

p.s. I'm out of work now so can't tell exact `ORA-` error number.

Comment: Oracle has a migration utility that might be able to just move the entire table for you.

Comment: What is a LONG BINARY in SQL Server, the documentation would indicate that this data type doesn't exist... Here is [Oracle's SQL-Server to Oracle conversion tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/gateways.102/b14270/apa.htm#i634210).

Comment: I wouldn't like to use any migration utility due the script should be run on daily basis

Comment: Exact error - ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got LONG BINARY when I use to_char at least. If I use to_blob it return ORA-22992: annot use LOB locators selected from remote tables

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do that with undocumented Oracle's package:

http://tonguc.wordpress.com/2008/08/28/how-to-transfer-long-datatype-over-dblink/

I would recommend tool called Pentaho Data Integration. This is free, small and superb ETL tool.

Download page: community(.)pentaho(.)com

It will recreated all tables and types for you. How to do it:

pldwh(.)blogspot(.)co(.)uk/2013/03/pentaho-data-integration-create-tables_1(.)html

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I have MsSQL beside dblink so once I use something like   SYS.dbms_metadata_util.long2varchar(4000,'"_abc"@MSDB','"_Type"',rowid) Oracle fails with message ORA-02070 database MSDB does not support ROWID in this context. It seems your suggestions is feasible  only between 2 oracle databases...

Comment: Oops! My bad! Wrong package... DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH. Link: http://connormcdonald.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/dbms_hs_passthroughthe-magic-package/